# #pragma mark or //MARK: equivalent for Java, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there is any equivalent for `#pragma mark` or `//MARK:` in Java with Eclipse?

Want to divide my code logically.

Few variants i found and that not work:

1)

```
//region
//endregion
```

2)

```
//================================================================================
// Title
//================================================================================
```

Comment: Nice question, too bad I never thought of asking myself